# FlashBuilder 4.7: How to make code link to its original class

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I recently upgraded to FlashBuilder 4.7 only to find some interface differences that I must fix. For some reason I cannot Command-click on a class or method to connect to that method or class. Can anyone tell me how to turn that feature back on. Also, what is the technical term for this affordance?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called 'Open declaration' if you right click on the Class name You should see 'Open Declaration' and shortcut key printed right next to it, in my case it is F3. I've looked up [Open declaration not working in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=flash%20builder%20open%20declaration%20not%20working&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS547US547&oq=Open%20declaration%20flashbuilder%20not%20work&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.8658j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the right-click on the class, but it did not work. I'll restart my machine to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I restarted my computer, and it still fails to work! However, I have found that it works on some files but not on others. This leads me to assume that there is a setting that will turn Open Declaration on/ off.

Comment: did you try and run the applicatoin? did you see any compilation errors?

Comment: Thanks Zeus-- that fixed the problem. I realized that I no longer had the correct SDK installed. I downloaded and applied the old SDK and everything now works!

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are missing is the Flash/Flex perspective. Find it from the views and amke sure it is selected.